# How to change the color of specific ticks in BarLegend?

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

I would like to set the color of the ticks as in colorbar such that "Cold" is `Cyan` while "Hot" is `Red`

```
BarLegend[{{Red, Black, Cyan}, {0, 1}}, 
 Ticks -> {{0, "Hot"}, {1, "Cold"}}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, Black}, LegendMarkerSize -> 236]
```

[image]

Comment: I posted a method that uses a defined `ColorFunction` if you find you want to use one of the interim colors in the future, rather than those at the endpoints. :D Not sure if it is entirely a better way to do it, but @kglr shows the key point of using `Style` to force the coloration of the labels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can wrap the tick labels with `Style`:

```
BarLegend[{{Red, Black, Cyan}, {0, 1}}, 
 Ticks -> {{0, Style["Hot", 13, Red]}, {1, Style["Cold", 13, Cyan]}}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 236]
```

[image]

Perhaps more flexibly, (whoops... this part is just a variation of the approach already posted by CA Trevillian)

```
cf = Blend[{Red, Black, Cyan}, #] &; 

BarLegend[{cf, {0, 1}}, 
 Ticks -> MapThread[{#, Style[#2, 13, cf@#]} &, {{0, 1}, {"Hot", "Cold"}}],
 LegendMarkerSize -> 236]
```

[image]

and

```
BarLegend[{cf, {0, 1}},
 Ticks -> {0, 1}, 
 "TickLabels" -> {Style["Hot", 13, cf@0], Style[ "Cold", 13,  cf@1]}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 236]
```

[image]

and

```
BarLegend[{cf, {0, 1}}, 
 "Ticks" -> {1, 0, .5}, 
 "TickLabels" -> {"Hot", "Warm", "Cold"}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (With[{col = cf[#]}, Style[#3, 13, col]] &)]
```

[image]

FWIW, using yet another undocumented option:

```
BarLegend[{cf, {0, 1}}, 
  "RotateLabels" -> 45 Degree, 
  "Ticks" -> MapThread[{#, Style[#2, 13, cf@#]} &, {{0, 1}, {"Hot", "Cold"}}],
 LegendMarkerSize -> 236]
```

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it haha. Nice! I wonder if there's a way to make the marks for the `Ticks` change according to the `ColorFunction` supplied? I was gonna post what you did here as a sort-of non-automated workaround.

Comment: @CATrevillian,  updated version shows a way to style the tick labels using the color function in the first argument of `BarLegend`.

Comment: That's awesome! (Your's is somehow cleaner than mine!) Clarification, must the `"TickLabels"` be defined in the order that they're supplied to `Ticks`? You could certainly beat me at codegolf with this!

Comment: `LabelingFunction` works as `”LabelingFunction”` here too, at least on WolframCloud! This makes me wonder, just how many “undocumented” options are there that work for these?!

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, this will produce what you want:

```
rbc := Blend[{Red, Black, Cyan}, #] &;

BarLegend[{rbc, {0, 1}}, 
Ticks ->
{
{#, Style["Hot", rbc[#]]}&@0,
{#, Style["Cold", rbc[#]]}&@1
}, 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, Black}, LegendMarkerSize -> 236]
```

First, you recognize that BarLegend automatically creates a `ColorFunction` using `Blend` to combine the colors provided to it. Then, you can discover you may define your own! This is the `rbc` that I define above. Finally, with some usage of `#` and `&` to encourage anonymous function assignments, you may get the same image as @kglr, so I will not repeat that here.

I think this will provide you with the freedom to define such things as `Ticks` markings which change color according to the `ColorFunction`, but that is out of the scope of this answer.

This can be applied also to kglr's answer, asked for in the comments how to rotate labels:

```
BarLegend[{rbc, {0, 1}}, 
Ticks -> {{#, Rotate[Style["Hot", rbc[#]], 90 Degree]} &@
0, {#, Rotate[Style["Cold", rbc[#]], 90 Degree]} &@1}, 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, Black}, LegendMarkerSize -> 236]
```

Produces:

[image: Image of BarLegend with rotated labels by 90 degrees.]

Comment: woow,  that is perfect. is it possibple to rotate (90 degree) the labels such that the two words "Hot" and "cold " are aligned along the color bar?

Comment: Do you want a `BarLegend` that is a `Row` instead of the default `Column` one?

Comment: No, only the labels.

Comment: Sure! Just wrap them in `Rotate` and specify your `Degree` of rotation! I'll post an update.

Comment: cool, thanks a lot!

Comment: Check update @HD2006